# Two arraylist to one recyclerview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, firebase

I have 2 Arraylists. One fetches SQLite data and one fetches Firebase Data

What i want to do is display the sqlite Data first and then below that the Firebase data... My SQLite data is mostly old data and firebase data is new. So i want the new data to be showed first and then if i swipe up the old one. Can i add 2 lists to same recyclerviews as both fetches different types of data

**SQLite**

```
               while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                    String mA= csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(A));
                    String mB = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(B));
                    String mC= csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(C));
                    String mD= csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(D));
                    String mE= csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(E));
                    String mF= csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(F));

                    list.add(new SQLiteHelper(mA, mV, mC, mD, mE, mF));

                }
```

**Firebase**

```
    Helper help= dataSnapshot.getValue(Helper.class);
    List.add(help);
```

Arraylist 1 = list (Old data)

Arraylist 2 = List (New Data)

*Can someone help me out please*

Answer (score 0):

You can just Create an Arraylist for the Adapter and then add the data you want to display first first and add the data you want to display below after that.

```
List<Helper> sqlite = ...
List<Helper> firebase = ...

List<Helper> helpers = new ArrayList<>();
helpers.addAll(sqlite);
helpers.addAll(firebase);

//TODO pass list to the adapter
```

Comment: But the helper class of both the data is different... Like one contains only string and other contains string int and boolean

Comment: @LaylaMcKenzy Then you can transform the one type into the other type or create a new Object which has boath atributes and in the recycler view you can inflyte a layout depending on the type of object you have.